# remove strikethrough behavior in chart.js bar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, legend, chart.js2, legend-properties

i am trying to change the look of the legends by removing the `strikethrough` effect , wihtout using `legendCallback` function in chart.js. The reason why i do not want to use the `legendCallback` function because i have my own custmizations in  `chart.options.legend.onClick`. hence if i use `legendCallback` i won't be able to use the `chart.options.legend.onClick`.

after carefully looking at the source of `Chart.js` i come to know that inside a draw function of `Chart.Legend` they are applying the `strikethrough` effect.

[Here is the link to plugin.legend.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/plugins/plugin.legend.js)

and here is the piece of code that applies the styling

```
    var fillText = function(x, y, legendItem, textWidth) {
            var halfFontSize = fontSize / 2;
            var xLeft = boxWidth + halfFontSize + x;
            var yMiddle = y + halfFontSize;

            ctx.fillText(legendItem.text, xLeft, yMiddle);

            if (legendItem.hidden) {
                // Strikethrough the text if hidden
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                ctx.moveTo(xLeft, yMiddle);
                ctx.lineTo(xLeft + textWidth, yMiddle);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        };
```

i want to know how shall we able to alter the behavior of the `strikethrough` just apply the fade effect when the legend is not active or hidden.

while searching for solution i came across this [codepen](https://codepen.io/ReioR/pen/YjGBrR) where in some has tried to override the functionality but unfortunately it is now working properly with the `chart.js version 2.7.3`

Link to [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7vfwLc6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now i have downloaded the indented version of chart.js and made following changes

```
var fillText = function(x, y, legendItem, textWidth) {
            var halfFontSize = fontSize / 2;
            var xLeft = boxWidth + halfFontSize + x;
            var yMiddle = y + halfFontSize;




        if (legendItem.hidden) {
            // Strikethrough the text if hidden , comment out the strikethrough code
            /*ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.moveTo(xLeft, yMiddle);
            ctx.lineTo(xLeft + textWidth, yMiddle);
            ctx.stroke();*/


           ctx.fillStyle = Chart.helpers.color(fontColor).lighten(0.75).rgbString();

        }
            ctx.fillText(legendItem.text, xLeft, yMiddle);
            ctx.fillStyle = fontColor;

    };
```

and in order to change the legend box color alter the drawLegendBox function as follow

```
if(legendItem.hidden){

    ctx.fillStyle = "#D6D6D6";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#D6D6D6";

}else{

     ctx.fillStyle = valueOrDefault$d(legendItem.fillStyle, defaultColor);
     ctx.strokeStyle = valueOrDefault$d(legendItem.strokeStyle, defaultColor);

}
```

i do understand this is not the right way to do. However, i really don't know how would i extend the Legend and override just the required part.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whvy6om2/)

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old (I don't think there are rules against posting on older posts) but in case anyone comes across this you can simply set onClick to null like this: (as well as change the legend's text color and size)

```
        options: {
          plugins: {
            legend: {
              onClick: null,
              labels: {
                color: "white",
                font: {
                  size: 18
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a better way doing that:

add onClick to legends and put this :

```
  const index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
  const ci = legend.chart;
  const isVisible = ci.isDatasetVisible(index);
  ci.setDatasetVisibility(index, !isVisible);


  // this is where the stroke remove happens
  const ci = legend.chart;

  const fillTextValue = ci.ctx.fillText;
  ci.ctx.fillText = function fillText(x, v, b) {
    fillTextValue.bind(ci.ctx, x, v, b)();
    this.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)"; // transparent color to set it invisible
  };
```

Comment: This does not remove strikethrough, it keeps it and the color you apply is added to the strikethrough dash itself.

Comment: @Kelb56
to remove the strikethrough you need to give it transparent color like in the example